# Memoryblock class gives a number after overflow, why and how?

Tags: c++, overflow

My mac laptop has a 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 memory.

In a classic MemoryBlock class,

```
class MemoryBlock
{
public:
    // Default constructor
    explicit MemoryBlock(): _length{0}, _data{nullptr} {}
    explicit MemoryBlock(const int l): _length{l}, _data{new int[l]} {}

    // Big-Five (blahblah)
    // --------

    int length() const
    {
        return _length;
    }

private:
    int _length;
    int* _data;
};
```

Then I tried to see what happens after overflow something like this, changing `x` from `1e9` to `1e10` to `1e11`.

```
MemoryBlock x(100000000000);
Info<< "x's length = " << x.length() << endl;
```

This gives me (compiled with `g++-6` and `cmake`),

```
[LOG]   x(   1000000000)'s length = 1000000000
[LOG]   x(  10000000000)'s length = 1410065408
[LOG]   x( 100000000000)'s length = 1215752192
```

warning is something like,

```
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
  MemoryBlock x(100000000000);
```

When using `size_t` as `_length` type, I won't be able to see this warning, not knowing why.

Anyway, my question is, how `1410065408` and `1215752192` are generated? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1215752192` is the result of `100000000000 % 2^32`, where `2^32` is the maximum representable value of a 32-bit integer *(which is the size of `int` on most platforms)*. Note that [**signed overflow is undefined behavior**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)!

Using `std::size_t` seems to either:

- increase the representable range to unsigned 64-bits *(on your particular platform, as it's [implementation defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t))*, so your `100000000000` won't overflow, and the behavior will be defined...
- ...or increase the representable range to unsigned 32-bits, where `100000000000` overflows *(but in a well-defined manner)*.

The only way to be sure of the previous claims is to verify what `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(std::size_t)` evaluate to on your machine, and figure out the exact overflows that are occurring in your code.

If you want to guarantee that a particular integer has a specific amount of bits, you should look into ["Fixed width integer types"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

---

[cppreference/Fundamental types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types) has a nice table containing the most common ranges for C++'s primitive types.

In the future, you can also use [`-fsanitize=undefined`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) to catch similar signed overflow issues.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I worded it very poorly. Hopefully it is less misleading now.

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes, this is quite tricky to get right without knowing the details about the OP's architecture. I'll try to improve the answer further